# Setting the default zone to trusted with firewall-cmd

Tags: rhel, firewalld

What is the meaning of the `--set-default-zone=trusted`?

```
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=trusted
```

and in which cases need to use `--set-default-zone=trusted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From firewalld documentation, [`man firewall-cmd`](http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html):

> --set-default-zone=zone
>
> Set default zone for connections and interfaces where no zone has been selected. Setting the default zone changes the zone for the connections or interfaces, that are using the default zone.
>
> This is a runtime and permanent change.

In [*trusted zone*](http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/zone/predefined-zones.html), all connections are accepted. If you do not trust all hosts in your network, you probably should use some more restrictive configuration.